# Show that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^2{x}\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^4{x}\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^2{x}\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx$$

$$J=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^4{x}\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx$$

How to show that $I=J={\pi\over 4}?$

---

$\sin^2{x}={1\over 2}(1-\cos(2x))$

$$I={1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx-{1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(2x)\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx$$

$$I=-{1\over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(2x)\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx$$

Going to apply IBP

Comment: Hint: $I = J \iff I-J = 0$ so you have to show $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^2{x}cos^2{x}\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx = 0$$… and obviously $$\sin^2{\frac{\pi}{4}}cos^2(\frac{\pi}{4})\ln(\tan{\frac{\pi}{4}}) = 0$$  and the function is odd around $\frac{\pi}{4}$… so…

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}J=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^4{x}\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx
\end{align}$

Perform the change of variable $\displaystyle y=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$,

$\begin{align}J&=-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^4{x}\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx\\
&=-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(1-\sin^2{x}\right)^2\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx\\
&=-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(1-2\sin^2 x+\sin^4 x\right)\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx\\
&=-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx+2I-J\\
\end{align}$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle J=I-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln(\tan{x})\mathrm dx$

But the latter integral is equal to $0$ (perform the change of variable $\displaystyle y=\frac{\pi}{2}-x$ )

Therefore,

$\displaystyle \boxed{J=I}$.